# Including hidden files in a war file using the jar command

Tags: linux, jar, war

I'm trying to create a war file on Mac OSX in terminal. I'm trying to include a hidden subdirectory of config files. For some reason the war file is not including the hidden subdirectory.

The command I am using is:

```
 jar cvf myWar.war *
```

File contents are two html files and one directory ".ebextensions"

Am I doing something wrong? Seems like this should be easier than I'm making it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try typing

`jar cvf myWar.war * .[!.]*`

With this command, you also include all directories/files, that begin with a dot, but exclude `.` and `..`.