# .ebextensions commands not running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a tomcat web application.
I added the .ebextensions under the root path.
.ebextensions contains a file called commands.config which has the following:

```
commands:
  command_test:
    command: touch hello-world.txt
    cwd: /home/ec2-user
```

After that i create the war file using:
For Tomcat web applications, use jar to create a web archive.

~/myapp$ jar -cvf myapp.war .

The problem is that the touch command is not executed.
The application is deployed successfully into Elastic Beanstalk but when i check the instance logs there is no mention about my command.
My guess is that i am placing the .ebextensions in the wrong path.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ssh to the EB instance to check if your file exists?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547817/including-hidden-files-in-a-war-file-using-the-jar-command/16548133

Comment: After checking the EB instance the file exists... Thank you @Marcin . But, does anybody knows in what logs can i see that the commands were executed? I am doing some debug with a custom  AMI on which EB cannot deploy the application and i would be interested to see which commands are executed. The official AWS documentations mentions to check the instance logs but there is no mention of my touch command there.